# Trigger Click event of anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclicklistener, jquery-events

I am trying to trigger the click event of an `a` tag using `jQuery` and have seen  many other Stack Overflow posts about this, but can't figure out why my replications of any of them are not working. My `HTML` is shown here:

```
        <c:url var="link" value="/hardwareItems" />
        <a href="${link}"  id="goToHardwareItems">Go
            to items</a>
```

And then here is my `jQuery/JS`:

```
$("#form").on("submit", function() {
    if (confirm("Add hardware items?")){
        $("#goToHardwareItems").trigger('click');
    }
    
    else {
        window.location.href = "/home";
    }
});
```

What I have is not working though, but when I actually click on the link, I am indeed taken to the page. So the problem is that the event is simply not triggering, even though I am also getting into the `if` statement. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This codepen may help you: https://codepen.io/enzogla/pen/GRqqvmW

Comment: You aren't considering the actual browser submit process of the form here. This seems like a strange set up. What is the point of the form if you are using it just to go to two alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value of `href` and redirect. You are already doing so.

```
$("#form").on("submit", function () {
    // Determine where to go based on user's response
    var link = confirm('Add hardware items?') ? $('#goToHardwareItems').attr('href') : '/home';
    window.location.href = link;
});
```